# Split one column into several sql

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have this table:

```
Path           Value Time
name1.metric1   v1  t1
name1.metric2   v2  t1
name1.metric3   v3  t1
name1.metric4   v4  t1
name2.metric1   v5  t2
name2.metric2   v6  t2
name2.metric3   v7  t2
name2.metric4   v8  t2
```

There are four metrics in the 'Path' for each user with different values. Time is the same for every metric of one user.

I want to know, how can I split 'Path' into another four columns, like this:

```
Path    metric1 metric2 metric3 metric4 Time
name1      v1     v2      v3      v4      t1
name2      v5     v6      v7      v8      t2
```

I use Clickhouse as DB, any ideas, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not intimately familiar with Clickhouse.  You basically need  conditional aggregation, along with some string operations on `path`.

Something like this:

```
select splitbychar(path, '.')[1] as name, time,
       max(case when path like '%.metric1' then value end) as value1,
       max(case when path like '%.metric2' then value end) as value2,
       max(case when path like '%.metric3' then value end) as value3,
       max(case when path like '%.metric4' then value end) as value4
from t
group by splitbychar(path, '.')[1], time
```

Comment: what if the data is having 100's of metrics values say for a minimum

Comment: @SashaKorkin Where do you run this query? This query is not following ClickHouse syntax and should not work.

Comment: you can use combinators maxIf(value, path like '%.metric1')

Comment: @vladimir I used “splitByChar” instead of “split”